# Can we change the color of comments or questions' text?

Tags: feature-request, comments

Is it possible to change the colour of comments text or of the text while asking questions. I know that we can make the text **bold**, *italics* etc.

But don't know how to change the text colour from black(default)to red,green etc.

Answer (score 8):

You can't. There is a very large downside to having colored text (i.e. it's very distracting) and very little upside.